# Count in Load statement is giving me error

Tags: sql, qlikview

This is my first time using qlikview and it is pretty simple since I have experience with SQL. I am doing it for a job application but I am having one issue.  I needed to do a count statement.  First is it best practice to put the count in the Load Statement or in the Select statement? or does it depend on the situation?  Second, I currently have it in the load statement and it is giving me an error.  Here is the code:

```
//This is the Order Details Table
OrderDetails:
LOAD OrderID & LineNo as OrderLineKey, OrderID, /*LineNo,*/ Discount, ProductID, Quantity, 
 UnitPrice, UnitPrice*Quantity*(1-Discount) as Sales, Count(ProductID) as ProductIDRecordCounter;
SQL SELECT OrderID, Discount, Quantity, ProductID, UnitPrice, LineNo
FROM `Order Details`
GROUP BY OrderID, ProductID, Discount, Quantity, UnitPrice, LineNo;
```

and this is the error it is giving me:

> Invalid expression SQL SELECT OrderID, Discount, Quantity, ProductID,
>   UnitPrice, LineNo FROM `Order Details` GROUP BY OrderID, ProductID,
>   Discount, Quantity, UnitPrice, LineNo

It worked prior to adding the count statement (and of course the group by which is necessary for the statement to work)

Answer (score 0):

The SQL statment will issue an SQL query, so first make sure that everything you have after the SQL statments runs when you execute against your database (using for instance SQL Management Studio, SQL Developer or some other tool that will allow you to test the SQL query).

The LOAD statment describes additional steps that Qlik will do over that data received from the preceding command (another LOAD or SQL). An a first glance I would say that you could transfer much of the logic you have on the LOAD statment to the SQL statment without causing much harm. I would discard completly the use of an additional LOAD command (on top of the SQL command) in your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Bruno. **If possible** move the `Group By` statement in the `SQL` select. You will not see much of a speed difference if your data is small but on big datasets the speed is noticeable (much faster in `SQL`)

Written like this the `Group By` clause is for the `SQL` statement but the actual aggregation function is in `QlikView` and because of this you are getting the error.

If you want to keep it like this (load from `SQL` and then aggregate in `QlikView`) your code should be:

```
OrderDetails:
LOAD 
  OrderID & LineNo as OrderLineKey, 
  OrderID, 
  /*LineNo,*/ 
  Discount, 
  ProductID, 
  Quantity, 
  UnitPrice, 
  UnitPrice * Quantity * (1-Discount) as Sales, 
  Count(ProductID) as ProductIDRecordCounter
GROUP BY 
  OrderID, 
  ProductID, 
  Discount, 
  Quantity, 
  UnitPrice, 
  LineNo;
SQL 
SELECT 
  OrderID, 
  Discount, 
  Quantity, 
  ProductID, 
  UnitPrice, 
  LineNo
FROM `Order Details`;
```